# C# 2 datasets in one asp.net chart

Tags: asp.net, sql, charts, dataset

I have two tables which I would like to dispaly on one graph, StockIssued and StockOrdered. I have SELECT statements which display the costs per month per year for both tables as below

```
SELECT YEAR(IssueDate) AS 'Year', MONTH(IssueDate) AS 'Month', SUM(TotalCost) AS 'TotalCostIssue'
FROM IssueStock
GROUP BY YEAR(IssueDate), MONTH(IssueDate)
order by 'Year', 'Month'  

SELECT YEAR(order_date) AS 'Year', MONTH(order_date) AS 'Month', SUM(cost) AS 'TotalCostOrder'
FROM Orders
GROUP BY YEAR(order_date), MONTH(order_date)
order by 'Year', 'Month'
```

Stock Issued
Year Month TotalCost
2010 ---1---    1500
2010 ---2---  1400
..........

Stock Ordered
Year Month TotalCost
2010 ---1---    1600
2010 ---2---  1700
...........

How can I display these costs for each month together on the same graph?

C# code

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        string SelectQuery1 = "SELECT YEAR(IssueDate) AS 'Year', MONTH(IssueDate) AS 'Month', SUM(TotalCost) AS 'TotalCost' " +
            "FROM IssueStock WHERE YEAR(IssueDate) = " + year + " GROUP BY YEAR(IssueDate), MONTH(IssueDate) order by 'Year', 'Month'";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(SelectQuery1, conn);

        myCommand.Connection.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;

        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Query");

        Chart1.DataSource = myDataSet;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Month";
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "TotalCostIssue";

        Chart1.DataBind();

        myCommand.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: Could you show the code how you fill your chart with one dataset?

Comment: Added C# code, fill a datasert from SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

As Your Two tables have the same structure. You can also use an `UNION ALL` clause on your `SQL` command. It is not the best solution but you will have the result.

```
string SelectQuery1 = "SELECT YEAR(IssueDate) AS 'Year', MONTH(IssueDate) AS 'Month', SUM(TotalCost) AS 'TotalCost' " +
        "FROM IssueStock  WHERE YEAR(IssueDate) = " + year ;
SelectQuery1 += " UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(IssueDate) AS 'Year', MONTH(IssueDate) AS 'Month', SUM(TotalCost) AS 'TotalCost' " +
        "FROM Orders WHERE YEAR(IssueDate) = " + year + " GROUP BY YEAR(IssueDate), MONTH(IssueDate) order by 'Year', 'Month'";
```

Comment: I have tried this but it gives a single cloumn called TotalCost there is no way to differentiate which TotalCost it is.

Comment: Sorted it by creating a temp table in a stored procedure